# If an empty set is an element of a set, $\{5,\{\}\}$ is that equal to just $\{5\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

Is this true $\{5, \emptyset\} = \{5\}$?

I know that the empty set is always a subset of any set, but when it's an element is that necessary to write in or not?

Comment: no, it is not true that the sets are equal.

Comment: They are not equal. The first is a set with two elements: $5$ and $\emptyset$. The second is a set with one element. These can't be the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are confusing being an element with being a subset.  It is true that $\emptyset \subset \{5\}$ but it is not true that $\emptyset \in \{5\}$.  This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

No. The empty set is still a set, not nothing.
A set is always something, in this case it's just a set *containing* nothing.

It's a subset of all sets, because you can always take out all their elements, but not an element since the set doesn't have an element that's a set with no items.

Therefore, no, they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.

$B \subset A$ means that $B$ is a subset of $A$, i.e. every element in $B$ is also in $A$. $e \in B \Rightarrow e \in A$.
So because the empty set $\emptyset$ contains no objects, $\emptyset \subset A$ for any $A$.

$\emptyset \in A$ is true only when $A$ contains the *element* "empty set", i.e. when $\{\emptyset\} \subset A$.

Let $B, C$ be sets. $A = \{B, C\}$ is the set containing as elements the two sets $B$ and $C$. $B$ and $C$ are elements of $A$.

$A' = B \cup C$ is the union of $B$ and $C$, i.e. the set containing all elements of $B$ and of $C$. $B$ and $C$ are subsets of $A'$.